# Comparing and updating elements of multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like below.

```
$test =   Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 38
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 7
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 232
                    [5] => 1
                    [6] => 58
                )


            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => 13
                    [2] => 7
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 232
                    [5] => 11
                    [6] => 58
                )


        )
```

and i want to push a array element like

```
$new =   Array
            (
                [0] => 38
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 7
                [3] => 2
                [4] => 232
                [5] => 1
                [6] => 58
            )
```

so it should be compare with all the inner array key elements of multidimensional array and if it matches with any of the inner array like $test[n][0] = $new[0],$test[n][1] = $new[1],$test[n][2] = $new[2],$test[n][3] = $new[3],$test[n][4] = $new[4] then the result should be like this.(because in our case $test[0] is matching)

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 38
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 7
                [3] => 2
                [4] => 232
                [5] => 2     ====> $test[0][5] + $new[5] //updating 1+1 = 2
                [6] => 58
            )


        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 8
                [1] => 13
                [2] => 7
                [3] => 2
                [4] => 232
                [5] => 11
                [6] => 58
            )


    )
```

and test array is having 'n' array in it.

Thank You any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($test as $key=>$val){
    if($val[0] == $new[0] && $val[1] == $new[1] && $val[2] == $new[2] && $val[3] == $new[3] && $val[4] == $new[4]){
        $val[5] = $val[5] + $new[5];
    }else{
        array_push($test, $new);
    }
}
print_r($test);
```